# How does turning categorical variables into dummy variables affect ANOVA results?

Tags: multiple-regression, anova, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I'm running a multiple linear regression with (amongst others) several categorical explanatory variables. My categorical variables are factors with several factor levels. For example, variable $x_1$ describes the number of residents in a dwelling and has the levels *1*, *2* and *>2*. Another variable describes when the dwelling was built, so it exhibits levels like *<1980*, *1980-1989*,... and so on.

Normally, using a linear model function, e.g. `lm()` in R, each categorical variable is reported as one variable in the ANOVA table. Only degrees of freedom are adjusted according to the number of factor levels.
(I'm using R, but i assume this works similarly with other software.)

However, since I have to use a model function in R that does not support categorical variables (in `plm()` all variables have to be numeric), I included each factor level as dummy variable, e.g.

```
y ~ ... + (x_1 == "1") + (x_1 == "2") + (x_1 == ">2") + ...
```

The question:

Are ANOVA results from both cases - i.e. including categorical variables *directly* or turning them into dummy variables according to their factor levels - the same? Is the second method (model) actually *correct*?

Answer (score 2):

Anova is really multiple regression for categorical variables, and is usually implemented via the use of dummy variables. Traditional formulas are only practical for a few, balanced designs. So the answer is **YES**---the answers are the same.

As for R's `plm` package and function, `plm` has a `formula` argument as is usual with R's modeling function, so your claim that all variables have to be numeric must be a misunderstanding.